WiFi Hotspot on second external USB card (Ubuntu 24)
On my laptop I have internal Wi-Fi adapter but also I have external USB Wi-Fi adapter. How can I enable Wi-Fi Hotspot on this external Wi-Fi adapter but not on internal?
When I select in Wi-Fi settings Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot... it just takes my internal Wi-Fi without asking anything.
